# Simpler method to insert a value into a potentially null pointer

Tags: c++, pointers

I have a pointer which I wish to point to an `LRESULT` which I am returning from a function. Currently, to insert the value returned from the function, I am storing it in a temporary variable then making the pointer point to that variable. I want to know if there is a way of doing this without the temporary variable.

Coded example follows:

```cpp
LRESULT* ret = nullptr;
//---
LRESULT temp = foo();
ret = &temp;
//---
return ret == nullptr ? bar() : *ret;
```

I have tried using this:

```cpp
*ret = foo();
```

But this does not work, as `ret` is a null pointer and has no assigned memory to put the value in.

I have also tried this:

```cpp
ret = &(foo());
```

But this does not work as well.

edit:

for context the full function I am working on is as follows:

```cpp
LRESULT CALLBACK Window::HandleMsgSetup(HWND hWnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)  noexcept
{
    LRESULT* ret = nullptr;
    if (msg == WM_NCCREATE)
    {
        const CREATESTRUCTW* const pCreate = reinterpret_cast<CREATESTRUCTW*>(lParam);
        Window* const pWnd = static_cast<Window*>(pCreate->lpCreateParams);
        SetWindowLongPtr(hWnd, GWLP_USERDATA, reinterpret_cast<LONG_PTR>(pWnd));
        SetWindowLongPtr(hWnd, GWLP_WNDPROC, reinterpret_cast<LONG_PTR>(&Window::HandleMsgThunk));
        LRESULT lr = pWnd->HandleMsg(hWnd, msg, wParam, lParam);
        ret = &lr;
    }
    return ret == nullptr ? DefWindowProc(hWnd, msg, wParam, lParam) : *ret;
}
```

and to once more reiterate, the function works fine in its current state, I merely wish to remove the seemingly unessecery variable `lr`

Comment: Please include a [mcve]

Comment: @ArdentCoder
I do not entirely understand what you mean by this, the code in its current state works fine and does not have any dangling pointers. I was simply asking if there is a more efficient way of doing it.
apologies for any misunderstanding.

Comment: @ArdentCoder
I copied that code and it gives me an error saying "expression must be an lvalue or a function designator"

Comment: @NathanielSmith My bad, I misunderstood it. I meant `ret = &(foo());` by dangling pointer. Please show us the code to make the problem more clear.

Comment: The lifetime of `lr` ends at the next `}`, so `ret` is a dangling pointer at that point. Maybe it "works fine" right now, since undefined behavior means anything could happen. But it might stop working at any point for a surprisingly large number of real-life reasons.

Comment: @RemyLebeau
Thanks!
with a bit of tweaking that worked perfectly.
I did end up having to change the last part to ```return ret ? *ret : bar()``` but thanks a lot. I was not previously aware of ```std::optional``` so thanks a lot for pointing that out to me

Comment: @aschepler
oh, that makes a lot of sense, have changed how I am working with it now so that no longer applies but I will certainly be sure to watch out for that in the future,
thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use a pointer, it must point to something valid, or else be null.  Anything else leads to undesirable results.

The code you have shown has **undefined behavior**, as you are accessing the memory for `lr` outside of its scope, after its lifetime has ended. The only reason your code seems to "work" is because that memory hasn't been overwritten yet when you dereference the pointer.

To solve that, you would have to move the declaration of `lr` outside of the `if` block:

```cpp
LRESULT CALLBACK Window::HandleMsgSetup(HWND hWnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)  noexcept
{
    LRESULT* ret = nullptr;
    LRESULT lr; // <-- MOVED HERE!
    if (msg == WM_NCCREATE)
    {
        const CREATESTRUCTW* const pCreate = reinterpret_cast<CREATESTRUCTW*>(lParam);
        Window* const pWnd = static_cast<Window*>(pCreate->lpCreateParams);
        SetWindowLongPtr(hWnd, GWLP_USERDATA, reinterpret_cast<LONG_PTR>(pWnd));
        SetWindowLongPtr(hWnd, GWLP_WNDPROC, reinterpret_cast<LONG_PTR>(&Window::HandleMsgThunk));
        lr = pWnd->HandleMsg(hWnd, msg, wParam, lParam);
        ret = &lr;
    }
    return ret == nullptr ? DefWindowProc(hWnd, msg, wParam, lParam) : *ret;
}
```

Alternatively, you can use [`std::optional`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/optional) (C++17 and later only) instead of a raw pointer, that will save you from having to declare a separate variable for it to refer to:

```cpp
#include <optional>

LRESULT CALLBACK Window::HandleMsgSetup(HWND hWnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)  noexcept
{
    std::optional<LRESULT> ret;
    if (msg == WM_NCCREATE)
    {
        const CREATESTRUCTW* const pCreate = reinterpret_cast<CREATESTRUCTW*>(lParam);
        Window* const pWnd = static_cast<Window*>(pCreate->lpCreateParams);
        SetWindowLongPtr(hWnd, GWLP_USERDATA, reinterpret_cast<LONG_PTR>(pWnd));
        SetWindowLongPtr(hWnd, GWLP_WNDPROC, reinterpret_cast<LONG_PTR>(&Window::HandleMsgThunk));
        ret = pWnd->HandleMsg(hWnd, msg, wParam, lParam);
    }
    return !ret.has_value() ? DefWindowProc(hWnd, msg, wParam, lParam) : ret.value();
}
```

However, the simplest solution would be to just eliminate the `LRESULT` variables altogether, as you don't actually need them:

```cpp
LRESULT CALLBACK Window::HandleMsgSetup(HWND hWnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) noexcept
{
    if (msg == WM_NCCREATE)
    {
        const CREATESTRUCTW* const pCreate = reinterpret_cast<CREATESTRUCTW*>(lParam);
        Window* const pWnd = static_cast<Window*>(pCreate->lpCreateParams);
        SetWindowLongPtr(hWnd, GWLP_USERDATA, reinterpret_cast<LONG_PTR>(pWnd));
        SetWindowLongPtr(hWnd, GWLP_WNDPROC, reinterpret_cast<LONG_PTR>(&Window::HandleMsgThunk));
        return pWnd->HandleMsg(hWnd, msg, wParam, lParam);
    }
    return DefWindowProc(hWnd, msg, wParam, lParam);
}
```

Comment: thank you for the ```std::optional``` answer I was unaware of that functionality previously.
using the two return statements was my original solution, however, my CS teacher always tells me it is bad practice to have multiple exits from a function so I try ad avoid that wherever possible.

Comment: @NathanielSmith Then your teacher is not doing you justice. In any case, you could just do this instead: `LRESULT ret; if (msg == WM_NCCREATE) { ... ret = pWnd->HandleMsg(hWnd, msg, wParam, lParam); } else { ret = DefWindowProc(hWnd, msg, wParam, lParam) } return ret;`

Answer (score 4):

I think you can do something like this then you can remove both **ret** and **lr** variables.

```
LRESULT CALLBACK Window::HandleMsgSetup(HWND hWnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)  noexcept
{
    if (msg == WM_NCCREATE)
    {
        const CREATESTRUCTW* const pCreate = reinterpret_cast<CREATESTRUCTW*>(lParam);
        Window* const pWnd = static_cast<Window*>(pCreate->lpCreateParams);
        SetWindowLongPtr(hWnd, GWLP_USERDATA, reinterpret_cast<LONG_PTR>(pWnd));
        SetWindowLongPtr(hWnd, GWLP_WNDPROC, reinterpret_cast<LONG_PTR>(&Window::HandleMsgThunk));
        return pWnd->HandleMsg(hWnd, msg, wParam, lParam);
    }
    return DefWindowProc(hWnd, msg, wParam, lParam);
}
```